# How do I prevent browser-sync from opening a new browser tab when I run it via npm scripts?

Tags: browser-sync, npm-scripts

I'm wanting to start browser-sync from an npm script.
At the moment when I do this, browser-sync opens a new browser tab.

That's a cool feature. But I don't want this to happen all the time.

I've tried using the parameter '--open false' to the command, but the w

This is the command that I'm using at the moment:

> browser-sync start --server dist --files 'dist/** --open false'

Comment: Replace `--open false` with the [`--no-open`](https://browsersync.io/docs/command-line) option - that prevents a new browser window being opened.